# Find entity class by using its table name

Tags: spring, maven, jpa

I have the name of a table . 
I want to retrieve entity class of this table in `Spring JPA`. 
The table name may differ from its entity class name.

I searched for a lot, but the solutions were to find the table name using the entity class . That is, quite the inverse is what I need.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to map entity class to a table name, you can get a list of all entity classes using JPA metamodel API, and subsequently build a complete inverse mapping.